# Why does Symfony 3.4 throw a ContextErrorException on a PHP Notice while Symfony 2.8 runs fine on the same code?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on migrating a `Symfony 2.8` project to `Symfony 3.4`. While the overall process is quite straight forward I stumble at one point:

While the code shown blow runs without any problem on `Symfony 2.8` it fails on `Symfony 3.4` with a `ContextErrorException`. The code is from a "Catch all" controller which handles calls to URLs which are not handled by any other route:

```
public function catchallAction(Request $request) {
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];     

    // Try to find a solution, e.g. by adding / replacing the locale
    if (1 === preg_match('/(\/app_dev\.php)?(\/([a-z]{2}))?(((\/([^\/]+))?(\/[^?]+))(\?(.+))?)/', $url, $matches)) {
        $this->logger->info('catchallAction');
        $this->logger->info("   $url");

        foreach ($matches as $key => $value)
            $logger->info("   $key => $value");

        $locale = (isset($matches[3]) ? $matches[3] : null);
        $subdir = (isset($matches[7]) ? $matches[7] : null);
        $path = $matches[5];
        $query = $matches[10]; 

        // ==> Exception in Symfony 3.4

        ...
    }

    ...
}

// Log output
catchallAction
    /app_dev.php/logout
    0 => /app_dev.php/logout
    1 => /app_dev.php
    2 =>  
    3 =>  
    4 => /logout 
    5 => /logout  
    6 =>  
    7 =>  
    8 => /logout
```

The exception message is correct, there is no index 10 in the `$matches` array. **However, I do not understand why this throws an exception in `Symfony**

- Both projects run the exact same server
- Both projects use the exact same PHP version with the exact same PHP.ini
- Both projects to to change/add PHP.ini settings in the .htaccess files (as far as I can see)

So, while both projects run in the same environment, `Symfony 2.8` runs fine while `Symfony 3.4` throws an exception on a PHP notice. Not even an error or warning but just a notice. How can this be and how to solve this?

Are there any other config files where `Symfony 3.8` changes the PHP settings?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find the solution:

`Symfony 3.2` introduced the `debug.error_handler.throw_at` parameter which controls on which PHP error (warning, notice, etc.) an exception is thrown.

Simply add the following to the config_dev.yml to only throw exceptions on errors. Maybe this answer helps others to spare some time :-)

```
parameters:
    # Avoid Symfony exceptions on PHP Warnings, Notices, etc., just handele error
    # PHP E_ERROR = 1
    debug.error_handler.throw_at: 1
```